# How to check if a string or char has Chinese char then display other char?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i want to check string or char every word.
if has chinese char show other char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[] = "Hello, 您Hi好!"; 
    string str1("Hello, 您Hi好!");
    printf("%s\n",ch);
    cout << "The string \"" << str1 << "\"'s size is " << str1.size() << endl;
      //for ch find the chinese char
      //if has chinese char show '|||'
      //normal to print
      //expect output:Hello, |||Hi|||!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your array probably have the Chinese characters UTF-8 encoded. You could iterate over the string, finding and resolving UTF-8 encoded sequences, and if the characters are "Chinese" do the replacement.

Comment: Also note that replacement will be much easier if you use C++ `std::string` objects instead of C-style null-terminated byte strings.

Comment: have u tried wchars ? `wchar_t` or `wstring`. i guess these can be useful for you

Comment: You need to know what the encoding is, then you use a library that's capable of classifying the characters according to script. The standard library has no support for this, and writing your own will both take ages and be wrong.

Comment: If you can, use Unicode [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) encoding for your source code and your strings, then use a library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) to work with your Unicode strings.  If you need to use a different encoding... good luck, that's a hard problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{

    char ch[] = "Hello, 您Hi好!";
    char c;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) {
        c = ch[i];
        if ((unsigned int)c >= 0x4E00u && (unsigned int)c <= ox9FFFu) {
            printf("|||");
        }
        else printf("%c", c);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why Error:identifier"ox9FFFu" is undefined

Comment: if not use char,string str1("Hello, 您Hi好!");

Comment: I hope you guys don't say before testing my solution yourself. I tested it and worked.

Comment: yes, i m testing after ask but cant identifier"ox9FFFu" i use Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I fixed your compilation error (you haven't tested this code yourself) and it doesn't work, as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d290318a36dadba). (I also added a space in the output to make it clearer.) Your comparisons are never true; if `char` is unsigned, `(unsigned int) c` is at most 255, and if it is signed, your cast gives values over four billion for the negative values.

Comment: @molbdnilo can use "string str1("Hello, 您Hi好!");" to Conversion?

Comment: @KwanNick No. Read my comment below your question. Handling non-ASCII text in C++ is complex and difficult.

Comment: @molbdnilo why the output is different?https://i.imgur.com/R6yGPS8.png http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/